# Cygwin,lib: command not found while building Unix based library

Tags: shell, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make, libtool

I am trying to install the [tblis](https://github.com/devinamatthews/tblis.git) library on my Cygwin installation and I am encountering in the following error:

```
$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/indiano/Test/tblis'
Making all in src/external/tci
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/indiano/Test/tblis/src/external/tci'
  CXXLD    lib/libtci.la
./libtool: line 1741: lib: command not found
make[2]: *** [Makefile:531: lib/libtci.la] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/indiano/Test/tblis/src/external/tci'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2581: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/indiano/Test/tblis'
make: *** [Makefile:1203: all] Error 2
```

I don´t have a lot of experience with building big projects and even less in cross-compiling, can somebody land an hand or at least point me in some direction?

My suspect is that something is missing in the base installation of Cygwin, but I can not identify which package should be.

Also seams that there is nothing to be found on the internet.

Comment: `lib` is not a Cygwin command. It seems the configuration assumes you are doing a Windows build. Any `configure` around ?

Comment: I am building on windows. "Any configure around ?" I do not quite understand what do you mean

Comment: When using `cygwin`, you configure the build like you do for `linux` instead of the way your would for a windows build.

Comment: Well, I did not touch the configure file that came with the repository, how could you tell that is trying to build for windows?